# Mocking Async method returns null

Tags: c#, moq

When exercising a test that invokes the following code,

```
var foo = _clientService.GetAsync<InvoiceContract>(new Uri(url));
viewModel.invoiceContract = **await** _clientService.GetAsync<InvoiceContract>(new Uri(url));
```

the first line works as expected, but the **await** is returning `null`.

The mock is setup as follows

```
_IHttpClientServiceMock
    .Setup(a => a.GetAsync<InvoiceFileContract>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>(), null))
    .ReturnsAsync(invoiceFileContract);
```

where the definition of `GetAsync` is

```
Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, string> customHeaders = default, AuthenticationDTO authenticationDTO = default);
```

Comment: Where is your setup? Please provide enough code and context. Please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please try to create a [mre]. Currently you don't even have the code that sets up the mock, which would be the bare minimum.

Comment: "it is not working" doesn't really help us understand the problem. Please explain what the problem is.

Comment: It seems like you are mocking a `GetAsync<>`  method with 3 parameters, yet you use overload with 1 parameter

Comment: @OlegI Not necessarily, in Moq, you need to provide all arguments to a setup, even optional ones. You can still call the method with only the required arguments. Which makes me think that the call doesn't work, because the setup doesn't match it. The last argument in the setup should probably be `It.IsAny<AuthenticationDTO>()` instead of `null`.

Comment: I just also noticed that you're caling `GetAsync<InvoiceContract>(new Uri(url))` but you're setting it up as `GetAsync<InvoiceFileContract>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), ...)`